# How to refer to a .jrtx template file from Jasper Report (.jrxml)?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_styles.htm) to apply a jasper template to jasper report. I am not able to find out how can I refer to jasper template from .jrxml file. The .jrxml file and .jrtx file are at the same location. In the Jasper I am referring to the template using following syntax.

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="QCReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20"
              topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0ea707c5-78f5-4f37-a065-a228202cb59e">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <import value="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"/>
    ..
    <template><![CDATA["JasperCustomStyle.jrtx"]]></template>
    ..
```

But it gives me  `Byte data not found at: JasperCustomStyle.jrtx.` exception. Can someone please help me figure out how to refer to a jasper template from .jrxml file?

Detailed Exception

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at: JasperCustomStyle.jrtx.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getBytesFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:210)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(JRXmlTemplateLoader.java:106)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillReportTemplate.loadTemplate(JRFillReportTemplate.java:111)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillReportTemplate.evaluate(JRFillReportTemplate.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.collectTemplates(JRBaseFiller.java:740)
```

The jrtx file looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperTemplate PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Template//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jaspertemplate.dtd">

<jasperTemplate>
    <style name="New style" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFC800" fill="Solid" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" isBold="true" isUnderline="true">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
</jasperTemplate>
```

Comment: What are the directory paths for the `.jasper`, `.jrxml`, and `.jrtx` files?

Comment: The .jrxml and .jrtx file are in rootFolder/reports folder. I am not saving .jasper files they are saved in JasperReport object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at: JasperCustomStyle.jrtx.
```

which means that the template can **not be found**.

You need to pass the correct path so that jasper can find the file, this is normally done by using parameters

**Example**

```
<template>$P{templateLocation} + "JasperCustomStyle.jrtx"</template>
<parameter name="templateLocation"/>
```

To parameter `templateLocation` you pass the absolute location of the folder that contains the templates (include the final `/`)

**or if an URL (in web application)**

```
<template class="java.net.URL">$P{templateURL}</template>
<parameter name="templateURL" class="java.net.URL"/>
```

To `templateURL` you pass the URL to the template, in web application you can also easily check that the template is available passing same URL to browser

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can i provide input stream in the <template> tag? I.e provide the parameter which is object of `java.io.InputStream`?

Comment: Yes, set class="java.io.InputStream"

Comment: In jasperserver application you should also be able to use relative path as `repo:templates/JasperCustomStyle.jrtx`, but I personally always prefer to use parameters so that application can be setup as I like from config files.

Comment: ok i provided template as InputStream object and it seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: or if you don't want relative (from template) path you can use absolute ( from resources folder ) like this:
`<template><![CDATA["repo:/bbb/styles.jrtx"]]></template>`

Answer (score 0):

Anyone wondering here for the solution, As of Jasper studio 6.11.0 we should use below code to import style component from external source to be added to jrxml file:

```
<template><![CDATA["http://linktomyStylesheet/Mystylesheet.jrtx"]]></template>
```